# ArcPy space in textfield

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-desktop

I got a tiny script:

```
def calc(value):
 if value is '123':
    return 'ok'
 elif value is '12 3':
    return 'not_ok'
 else:
    return value
```

if the value is without spaces it works perfectly, but if there is a space in it, it just returns the value.
Where is my error? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use `is` try the `==` operator.

Comment: This is a Python question, not specific to arcpy.

Comment: Strictly speaking I suspect it is an ArcGIS Field Calculator question related to its Python parser but nevertheless I agree that it is more about Python than ArcGIS.